# iMacros data extraction and comparison

Tags: imacros

Is it possible to extract and compare the contents of the website using imacros? I would like to extract data and compare using some pre-defined information and thus modify only some fields rather than ensuring all fields within a page are set to a default. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is.

You can use macro to extract information and save it in JavaScript variable. And let's say you scraped data from 2 websites and if both have keyword "foo bar" you alert "foo bar found".

```
var test1=website_text1.search(/foo bar/gi);
var test2=website_text2.search(/foo bar/gi);


if (( test1>=0 ) && (test2 >=0 ))
{

alert("foo bar found");

}
else
{

alert("foo bar is not on both websites");

}
```

For the full code of what you explained it will take more information.

Answer (score 0):

why not extract it in a csv file ..then use the csv as a database to compare whatever variable you might be needing,you can go futher by creating a macro to automate the csv macro comparion.make a google search on macros for csv.

Comment: How do I create a macro to automate the csv macro comparison?

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure what exactly you need. 
iMacros cannot perform such tasks by itself, you need scripting - either basic javascript or whatever else you know how to use (java, php, etc)

Anyway, I believe **Selenium** http://docs.seleniumhq.org/ may be closer to what you need. You should give it a try.